# Get only users who do not have the id equal to a condition (SQL)

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables, user:

| id | full_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Beatriz |
| 2 | Mauro |
| 3 | Jose |
| 4 | fran |

approver :

| id | subordinate_id | approver_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |

I would like to bring up the names of people who are not registered in the subordinate_id column

I did the following query:

```
SELECT 
    U.full_name
FROM user AS U
INNER JOIN approver as A
ON U.id <> A.subordinate_id ;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DldM4.png)

and still users are coming in that are in the subordinate_id column of the approver table.
I would like to get the result only for user names that are not subordinate_id, can someone help with this?

I would like a result with only the users that are not subordinate_id

Comment: To clarify, your approach isn't working because user ID 3 matches the row with approver ID 1, and user ID 1 matches approver ID 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple to accomplish an ansi-sql with a *not exists* semi join:

```
Select full_name
from user u
where not exists (
  select * from approver a
  where a.approver_id = u.id <-- or (subordinate_id, whichever it should be)
);
```